# jQuery scrollTop function not working on IOS

Tags: jquery, ios, mobile-safari, scrolltop

I have the following code which works fine on desktop browsers but does not work on iPad or mobile devices. What I have is a 65px high nav bar fixed to the bottom of the browser window and once the page scrolls to the end of the content the nav bar grows to 120px revealing some other footer links (T&Cs Privacy statement etc) and social media icons.

Can anyone advise what I need to do to make this code work on other devices?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())
    {
        // show container
        $('nav').stop(true).animate({
            'height':'120px'
            },{ queue: false, duration: 500 });          
    }
    else
    {
        $('nav').stop(true).animate({
            'height':'65px'
            },{queue: false, duration: 500});          
    }
});

$('nav').on('click', function() {
    $('nav').stop(true).animate({
            'height':'65px'
            },{queue: false, duration: 500});   
});
</script>
```